# Why a hole in the Dirac sea can be seen as having opposite energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, dirac-equation, antimatter

In the Dirac's old attempt of relativistic quantum mechanics, a hole in the $E'$ level of the Dirac sea was interpreted as a particle of opposite charge and positive energy. I do get why it can be seen as having opposite charge but I don't get why it can be interpreted as having opposite energy. Any ideas?

Comment: The equation produces solutions with negative eigenvalues, so it's an unfortunate/unwanted mathematical feature, rather than a matter of interpretation.

Comment: @CuriousOne  Why would negative eigenvalues be 'unwanted'?

Comment: There is no such thing as the Dirac sea. The closest thing is a valence band in a semiconductor or metal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ground state of Dirac sea is full of particles with negative energy, according to Dirac equation. When a particle/electron absorbs energy and excites to a positive energy state with energy level $E$, it will leave a hole with energy $E-E\prime$ (if the total energy absorbed is $E$) , which is positive according to energy conservation. So the hole seems to have positive energy.

Answer (score 0):

The hole has to have positive energy because if we want to make it disappear we would have to add an electron with negative energy to the system.